# Proper integral $\int \frac{1}{\left ( x^{2}+4 \right )^2}dx$

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{1}{\left ( x^{2}+4 \right )^2}dx$$

I have tried to put t instead of $x^{2}+4$ but couldn't get anything.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Have you learned about trigonometric substitutions?

Comment: @KM101 yes, I know them

Comment: So what should you do when you see integrals with $a^2+x^2$?

Comment: @KM101 $1/a\(arctan \frac{x}{a})$, is it?

Comment: Use $x=2 \sinh t$, or $x= 2\tan t$. Due to $\sinh^2 t +1 = \cosh^2 t$ and $\tan^2 t +1 = \sec^2 t$ the integrand will simplify.

Comment: It's $x = a\tan(t)$ or $t = \arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)$. From here, you should be able to work it out.

Comment: @Mick I don't have any idea what's sinh yet, but still thanks)

Comment: @KM101 I do it like that,but the answer is not correct

Comment: You should edit your question to show your work. Otherwise, how could we figure out where you went wrong?

Comment: @KM101 I did as u said and everything went correctly but there is some additional numbers in the answer

Comment: After substituting $x = 2\tan(t)$ and simplifying the integrand, you're left with $\dfrac{1}{8}\displaystyle\int \cos^2(t) \, \mathrm dt$. All that's left is using $\cos^2(t) = \dfrac{1+\cos(2t)}{2}$ and you'll get everything in terms of $t$. Working back to get the result in terms of $x$ isn't that tricky. Again, like I said, I have no idea what your problem is since you haven't shown your work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105039/discussion-between-jane-and-km101).

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$d\left( \frac x{x^2+4} \right) = \frac{8dx}{(x^2+4)^2} - \frac{dx}{x^2+4}$$

Then,

$$\int \frac{dx}{\left ( x^{2}+4 \right )^2}
=\frac18\int d\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+4 }\right) + \frac18 \int\frac{dx}{x^2+4} 
=\frac18\frac{x}{x^{2}+4 } + \frac1{16} \tan^{-1}\frac x2+C$$

Comment: thanks a lot)))

Comment: @jane - you’re welcome